# Text.Printf with Data.Text?

Tags: haskell

I got sick of unpacking `Data.Text` instances all the time before printing them out for debugging and thought to just use `Text.Printf` for that.  Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Text
import Text.Printf

--instance PrintfArg Text where
--  toUPrintf = toUPrintf . unpack

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input :: Text = "abc"
  printf "Input: %s\n" input
```

The error:

```
src/Main.hs:12:3:
    No instance for (PrintfArg Text)
      arising from a use of `printf'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (PrintfArg Text)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: printf "Input: %s" input
    In the expression:
      do { let input :: Text = "abc";
           printf "Input: %s" input }
    In an equation for `main':
        main
          = do { let input :: Text = ...;
                 printf "Input: %s" input }
```

After uncommenting the instance declaration:

```
src/Main.hs:7:7:
    `toUPrintf' is not a (visible) method of class `PrintfArg'
src/Main.hs:7:19: Not in scope: `toUPrintf'
```

Any ideas?

EDITED

As suggested, tried TH, still no go:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Text
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Text.Printf

runQ [d| instance PrintfArg Text where toUPrintf = toUPrintf . unpack|]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input :: Text = "abc"
  printf "Input: %s\n" input
```

Error:

```
src/Main.hs:9:40:
    'toUPrintf' is not a (visible) method of class 'PrintfArg'
src/Main.hs:9:52: Not in scope: 'toUPrintf'
```

Help!  It's amazing this doesn't work out of the box given all the advice to use Data.Text by default.

Comment: Get the printf package and export the PrintfArg class and use that instead of the usual package.

Comment: @augustss: printf is in base, not a separate package.  And maybe enough stuff could be exported so that users could create their own PrintfArg instances?

Comment: I'll add a Text.Printf.Internal module to expose all the type classes and types involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**WARNING: text-format is unmaintained, no response from the author in 2 years. See other answers.**

---

I'd look at the [text-format](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format) package: it is similar to `Text.Printf`, but specifically designed for `Data.Text.Lazy`.

There are a few other advantages of text-format over `Text.Printf`:

- The [`Buildable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-format/0.3.0.7/doc/html/Data-Text-Buildable.html) class is exposed, so it can be extended to support new parameter types.
- It uses a simpler approach to varargs, which sidesteps problems one has in `Text.Printf` with [accessing the return value](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2009/09/25/riddle-me-this/).
- It should be much faster, for several reasons:

  - it never converts to the inefficient `String` representation;
  - it doesn't build intermediate datatypes, unlike [`UPrintf`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Text-Printf.html#UPrintf) in `Text.Printf`;
  - it uses the [double-conversion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/double-conversion) package for rendering `Double` and `Float`, which is about [30 times faster](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/) than Prelude's methods.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing `TF.print "Input: {}\n" $ TF.Only input`.

Comment: How do you do the classical printf-formatting stuff like `%.02f` with it?

Comment: Is there documentation on how Data.Text.Format.Format reads it's IsString instance? Can I use the standard `printf` format characters with it?

Comment: They have an issue open since 2014 about lack of documentation, don't waste your time

Comment: There is now an [instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html#t:PrintfArg) that works with `Data.Text`

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was asked, the `base` and `text` libraries have been updated to support this. If you have *base >= 4.7.0.0* and *text >= 1.2.2.0*, then the OP's MWE actually works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Text
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input :: Text = "abc"
  printf "Input: %s\n" input
```

Output:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> main
Input: abc
*Main> 
Leaving GHCi.
```

Comment: Is there a printf like function that returns a value of type Text, i.e. like sprintf in C

Comment: I guess [hPrintf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:hPrintf) can do this.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The HPrintfType class provides the variable argument magic for hPrintf. Its implementation is intentionally not visible from this module.

While you could use TH to generate HPrintfType instances (because TH ignores export restrictions) the easiest solution is probably a `printf'` type function:

```
printt :: PrintType r => Text -> r
printt = printf . Data.Text.unpack
```

Comment: Doesn't work either:

src/Main.hs:12:3:
    No instance for (PrintfArg Text)
      arising from a use of 'printt'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (PrintfArg Text)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: printt "Input: %s" input
    In the expression:
      do { let input :: Text = "abc";
           printt "Input: %s" input }
    In an equation for 'main':
        main
          = do { let input :: Text = ...;
                 printt "Input: %s" input }

Comment: Ohh, how silly of me.  You want more than the format string to be useful obviously.  Well I think you'll need to add the instance into the printf module or use TH.

Answer (score 1):

Another package worth checking out: [formatting](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting/docs/Formatting.html)

> Combinator-based type-safe formatting (like printf() or FORMAT) for Text.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> format ("Person's name is " % text % ", age is " % hex) "Dave" 54
> ```

Comment: It no longer depends on double-conversion or text-format.